How to represent multiple chains of events in Event Storming?
When I try to model a system with event storming, every now and then I arrive at a situation where user can run one of the several commands. How do I represent that in a timeline?
For example, let's consider a forum.
"User created topic" chain would go first.
"User deleted topic" would probably go last.
But "User edited post" and "User posted to topic" aren't ordered - as soon as topic has been created, there is a post in it which can be edited.
How do I represent that? Do I draw multiple 'lanes'? Do I put those chains in any order?
